# Microsoft Graph API: Java SDK- How to use orderby? for API call on driveItems by lastModifiedDateTime

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

So I am listing all the driveItems in a folder like this

```
mGraphServiceClient.drives().byId(rootDrive.id).items(driveItemFolder.id).children().buildRequest().get()
```

How can I add order by lastModifiedDateTime like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#orderby-parameter

Answer (score 1):

To add query params in the Java sdk one should create a list of `QueryOptions` and pass it into the `buildRequest` function.

To have something that looks like this.

```
LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<Option>();
requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$orderby", "lastModifiedDateTime"));

GraphServiceClient.drives().byId(rootDrive.id).items(driveItemFolder.id).children().buildRequest( requestOptions ).get()
```

Comment: Seeing that makes me sad.  We really need a shorter way of doing that.